Shall we rethink "the Meta site should be in English only"?
There's a clash between

The Meta site should be in English only, though. This is a request by the Stack Exchange team so they can communicate with us.
Chinese.SE On-topic

and

We used to say if you want us (the Community Team) to be familiar with your community issues, meta posts would have to be in English. But on the rare, rare occasion where this was ever an issue, a post is easily Google-translated. In reality, meta is for the community, so they should post in whichever language is most comfortable for them. The reason to try and enforce "you can post {spanish} everywhere... except meta", in my opinion, was too obscure to worry about in actual practice, so I never worried about it.
Robert Cartaino ♦, 2016.

In practice, questions in the relevant language on language-related meta sites comprise...

Virtually all posts at Ukrainian.meta.SE and Rus.meta.SE (Russian language in Russian);
Frequent posts at German.meta.SE, Spanish.meta.SE, French.meta.SE, and Portuguese.meta.SE;
Some (but not many) at Russian.meta.SE and Italian.meta.SE; and
No (or virtually no) posts at Japanese.meta.SE, Korean.meta.SE, Latin.meta.SE, and Esparanto.meta.SE.

I currently see no reason to exclude Chinese from meta.SE.  For the rare posts where we want Stack Exchange staff to respond directly, we can easily include an English translation of the relevant parts (that's basically what we do here).  There seems to be a good reason not to exclude Chinese: What if a user doesn't speak English?  (The same reason for the main site.)
Question: Shall we rethink "the Meta site should be in English only"?
I guess it'd be a problem if someone posts here in e.g. Tibetan, but I'm sure anyone who speaks Tibetan would realize this.
